# The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I get the following exception running a stored procedure:

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported.

The procedure is defined like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTest (
@p1 varchar(1024) ,
@p2 varchar(1024) ,
@p3 char(1) ,
@p4 varchar(254),
@p5 varchar(254),
@debug bit )
```

My parameters in Java are defined like this:

> Object[] params = {"1,2,3", "d", '2', "", "", 1};

I think it's caused by the character. Any ideas why?

Comment: Try using a `String` `"2"`, as 'char' is still actually string data (it can have multiple lengths, after all).  Otherwise, I'm suspicious of 'bit', as Java doesn't really have an equivalent type...

Comment: Yeah it's the char type causing grief.  Converting to String makes it work.

Comment: Found this question when dealing with a Java enum - explicitly converting that toString() when adding to the param array fixed my problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found it.  Clockwork-Muse put me on the path. The char type does not convert to an Object when you set the parameters. The following will work:

```
     try (PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
        int n = 1;
        for (Object o : params) {

            if (o instanceof Character) {
                o = "" + o;
            }

            st.setObject(n, o);
            n++;
        }
        st.executeQuery();
    }
```

Comment: Actually, it probably is, it just ends up being autoboxed to it's [object representation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html), which just doesn't happen to be `String`.  You'd be better off converting it when you set the actual parameters, as that'll make it more clear what you're doing.  Also, if you need the index, just use a traditional for-loop, don't mix like this.

Comment: Similarly, `Optional` has no conversion in the SQL Server driver, so this error will happen if one forgets to unbox the `Optional` (using `orElse(null)` in most cases).

Answer (score 3):

This error can occur, if you use `jdbcTemplate.update(sql, List<Object[]>, int[])`, but instead you wanted to use `jdbcTemplate.`**`batchUpdate`**`(sql, List<Object[]>, int[])`.

It compiles, because there is a `jdbcTemplate.update(sql, Object...)` method in jdbcTemplate, but it will yield "The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported.", because it cannot use `List<Object[]>` as parameter.

Comment: What is the solution for this?

Comment: @ammy Use `batchUpdate` instead of `update`.