# The conversion from UNKNOWN to VARCHAR is unsupported

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get the following error when i go for inserting the data in the database.

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from UNKNOWN to VARCHAR is unsupported.

Here is my table structure.

```
[DETECTION_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
[CUSTOMER_ID] [varchar](54) NULL,
[CUST_NAME] [varchar](46) NULL,
[ACCOUNT_ID] [varchar](35) NULL,
[TRAN_ID] [varchar](86) NOT NULL,
[BUSINESS_DATE_TIME] [datetime] NULL,
[TRAN_AMOUNT] [float] NULL,
[TRAN_CODE] [varchar](13) NULL,
[PLAY_ID] [varchar](56) NOT NULL,
[SCHEME] [varchar](39) NULL,
[DETECTION_ID] [varchar](84) NOT NULL,
[SR_START] [datetime] NULL,
[SR_END] [datetime] NULL,
[ALERT_PLAY_ID] [varchar](37) NULL
```

What i am doing here is, i fetch tha data from some other table and store the values in this table, and during storing the values in this table i get this error.

I dont know why am i getting this error.
Can anyone tell me what could the problem?

Is this happening while i am storing the data in this table or i am getting some wrong value while fetching the values from other table?

Please help.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Reduce the number of columns until you know which one it is. Then reduce the data rows until you know what row it is. Then fix the data?

Comment: preet- The problem is that i dont have any data to test. I just want to know that in which scenarios we could get this kind of error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684734/the-conversion-from-unknown-to-unknown-is-unsupported)

Comment: Flagged as duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684734/the-conversion-from-unknown-to-unknown-is-unsupported, another guy just got the same problem and solved it

Comment: Show the code where you do the insert not just the error message.