# SQLServerException: The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported using Groovy

Tags: sql, sql-server, grails, groovy

I am trying to run a query using Groovy SQL against a SQL Server DB. However, I am receiving the following exception: `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported`

```
Grails version: 2.2.5
SQL Server version: 9.0
```

**The script I am running from the Grails console:**

```
import groovy.sql.*

Sql sql = Sql.newInstance(ctx.dataSource_sqlserver)

def query = '''
    select
        avg(cast(score as decimal)) average_score
    from
        StudentQuestionScores
    where
        id in ( :ids )
        and question = :question
'''

def ids = Student.list().collect { it.id }  // Succeeds
def row = sql.firstRow(query, [ids: ids, question: 'Insert Question Here']) // ERROR

sql.close()

println row.average_score // Never makes it here :(
```

Does anyone know why this might be or how I can fix it? Thank you!

**Stacktrace:**

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DataTypes.throwConversionError(DataTypes.java:1117)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setObject(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setObjectNoType(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:926)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setObject(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:935)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setObject(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:169)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setObject(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:169)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.setObject(Sql.java:3649)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.setParameters(Sql.java:3614)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.getPreparedStatement(Sql.java:3875)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.getPreparedStatement(Sql.java:3922)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.access$900(Sql.java:227)
    at groovy.sql.Sql$PreparedQueryCommand.runQuery(Sql.java:4078)
    at groovy.sql.Sql$AbstractQueryCommand.execute(Sql.java:4027)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.rows(Sql.java:1945)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.rows(Sql.java:1835)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.rows(Sql.java:1816)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
```

Comment: It's likely to be your `list`, you generally can't parameterise a list of values.  Try it with one value and see if it works, if so you'll need to research the different options available for passing lists of values in to an SQL query.  There are several, each with it's own trade-offs.

Comment: That does seem to be the issue. Removing the `id in (:ids)` part makes the query work. Any idea how I can pass in a list of strings as a parameter?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684734/the-conversion-from-unknown-to-unknown-is-unsupported) might be a duplicate question. Try using double quotes for question param. `question: "Insert Question Here"`

Comment: I don't think id will be varchar in db. but still you can try using `ids*.toString()` in the parameters along with my comment above.

Comment: @dmahapatro You're right, it typically wouldn't be, but in this case it is a student ID, which is stored as a String.