# Passing ArrayList to sql server procedure argument using callablestatement in spring

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, stored-procedures, arraylist

I am facing some issue while passing the ArrayList as object to the sql server strored procedure. In SQL server i have a table type created and that is passed as an argument to the procedure. But when passing the List as a argument in callablestatement getting the issue as

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from
>   UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GRP_SCR]
(@GRP_DET TBL_GRP_DET READONLY,
 @PLST_UPD_BY VARCHAR(600));

CREATE TYPE TBL_GRP_DET AS TABLE 
( Grpid INT);
```

Could anyone help on resolving this issue and how can i pass a arraylist to sqlserver.

Comment: Have a look - http://stackoverflow.com/q/17684734/4290096

Comment: Thanks for your reply @javy, but i am passing the object directly to the procedure.